# I have a budget document that is used by multiple external suppliers. I want to lock sheets so they can each only see their own project

Tags: excel, vba

As above, I have a budget document that is used by multiple external suppliers.
This is made up of 1 internal master sheet (internally used) which pulls from 10+ individual project sheets.

I want to ensure that my external suppliers can only see the contents of their project sheets and not the others or the master sheet.

My plan has been to have a "home" sheet which everyone lands on, with a contents list hyperlinking to the other sheets, which are then password protected. Each supplier would know the passwords only for the sheets they should see.

Eg.

[image]

This is what I've been working with so far on the workbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim xSheetName As String
xSheetName = "Client 1"
If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    xTitleId = "Please enter Client 1 Password"
    response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    If response = "1" Then
        Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
        Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Select
    End If
End If
Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This does work if I just have it on one sheet; I click on the Client 1 sheet tab and it requests the password, once entered the sheet is then opened. This solution works perfectly, as unlike other solutions I've found on Stackoverflow, this doesn't require any hiding of sheets.

My main question is: How do I repeat this so it does the same thing on the other sheets?? I appreciate this may be a very stupid question, forgive me!

Comment: Excel security is easy to bypass with the right info.  It might be better to have code that pushes your client sheets to individual files which can be sent to them. No chance of them seeing info they shouldn't then.

Comment: Thanks! This is all on a live sharepoint file so we want them to have access to it regularly and we don't want to have to maintain multiple files. For clarity, legally there's no issue with one supplier seeing another project, it's more around keeping costs hidden for our negotiation with those suppliers.

Comment: I agree with @Darren Bartrup-Cook, best to have a separate workbook for each supplier, which you share with just that supplier. It also means they can edit the file using Excel on-line as it is less likely you need any VBA to manage access.

Comment: Darren Bartrup-Cook is right - I know this from personal experience of taking over a similar project. However, if you insist on going down the password line put the password capture in the Workbook.Open. Use your current method or better would be xlVeryHidden to hide sheets (they don't appear in the Unhide list).
To generate multiple files from a Master (you only "maintain" the master) you could use VBA or Scripting and link to a Power Flow or Power Automate

Comment: Chill60, thanks. I'd like to try the password option for now but will definitely consider multiples workbooks linking into a master one.

Could you clarify what you mean by "put the password capture in the workbook.open"? I already have the one above but that only applies to Client 1. How do I separate them so it runs on all sheets independently?